# Query conversion from db4o to hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, db4o, object-oriented-database

I'm currently working on a project to implement an OODB (object oriented database) cache where the requirements are to use a db4o database as the cache and store objects in it. My backend database is in MySQL and I am using Hibernate to get the data from it and form objects.

I can query for objects in db4o using their native query or query by example methods and in hibernate i can use HQL or SQL to get data from the RDBMS. However my problem lies in how to bridge the gap between db4o and Hibernate and convert the query as needed (I'm using both since the requirements have been given like that).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is no real bridge, as far as I know. You basically need to write your query two times.

Once there was db4o support in [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) with a JPA / JDO wrapper. However afaik it didn't support JPQL (Hibernate supports JPQL). And they also dropped the db4o support meanwhile, because it wasn't maintained well.

So, the answer is: There no nice solution for your query issue.

What should your caching layer be able to do? Why did you choose db4o? Why can't you use the regular second level cache, like Ehcache, which is integrated in Hibernate?